# CacheBuilder Initialization in constructor do not use Spring annotation value

Tags: spring

I'm working on a functionality which works with google reCaptcha. During tests there is something wrong with CacheBuilder: expireAfterWrite value is always set = 0 (14400 is declared in anntoation and in application-test.properities as well). As i suppose something is wrong becouse it is initialized in constructor. Is there any other way to initialize it?

```
public class RecaptchaService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${recaptcha.url:}")
    private String recaptchaUrl;

    @Value("${recaptcha.secret:#{null}}")
    private String recaptchaSecret;

    @Value("${recaptcha.fail.silent:false}")
    private boolean recaptchaFailSilent;

    @Value("${recaptcha.failAttempts.expire:14400}")
    private int recaptchaAttemptExpire;

    @Value("${recaptcha.failAttempts.max:4}")
    private int maxAttempts;

    private LoadingCache<String, Integer> attemptsCache;

    private int attempts;


    public RecaptchaService(final RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        attemptsCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(recaptchaAttemptExpire, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer load(final String key) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved you problem?

Answer (score 0):

We will assume that there is an `@Component`, or equivalent, annotation on your service.

In fact during the construction of your object, values are not yet injected. Then in your constructor `recaptchaAttemptExpire` equals to 0 (even if you set a default injection value).

As it seems to be a Service, then try to intialize your `attemptsCache` field during a `@PostConstruct` method maybe?

Comment: Really?  I seem to have a bunch of code that shows the values are available in the constructor,

Comment: In fact it's very simple: While the object is no existing, you can't inject the value. But you could inject the values **IN** the constructor if it is manage by spring.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like RecaptchaService isn't being managed by spring.  I don't see a @Component annotation.  I'm surpised the @Value annotations work at all in an un-managed bean!

If you let spring manage the life-cycle of RecaptchaService then those values will be available in the constructor.